# How do I update my MacBook Pro to the latest version of BootCamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Running Windows 8.1 on my 2013 Macbook Pro that runs OS X 10.10.5.

Want to update the version of BootCamp (and related drivers) that it is running - I don't think it has updated since I partioned and installed Windows 3-6 months ago and I know there have been updates.

1. I was notified within Windows via Windows Update of new BootCamp and tried the update via Windows update but it failed
2. Running `Apple Software Update` within Windows doesn't give me anything BootCamp related to download & install - [this Apple Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990)  says that it will be available via this channel but it's not?
3. The options from within Yosemite + BootCamp all seem to entail a re-partition and reinstall of my entire Windows partition (naturally not first prize)
4. Download of drivers onto a USB stick from Apple website but this also seems to involve a re-partition.

My end goal is to perform the free upgrade to Windows 10 without reinstalling but I am trying to get BootCamp in order from the beginning.

Related question: how can I tell precisely which version of BootCamp I am actually running. From within Windows I can right click on `About Boot Camp` and it says 5.1 but this is not specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open BootCamp Assistant and open the about window. You should be similar to Version 5.1.4 (500) if you are on 10.10.5

BootCamp gets updated when you update OS X so it's really not dependent upon any version of Windows whatsoever so you would be up date on BootCamp even if you deleted your windows partition and started over.

Answer (score 1):

As @bmike♦ said, BootCamp gets updated when you update OS X: indeed i'm running 10.11 and i've got Boot Camp Assistant version 6.

Now, i did the same thing: i updated from Windows 8 to Windows 10 and i didn't need to update any drivers whatsoever.
I had my Windows 8 installed with BootCamp Drivers (but i didn't had the whole partition thingy because I installed Windows on an external hard drive) and i was able to upgrade to Windows 10 without touching the drivers at all. It was really nice and straightforward, just like I was running a proper Windows PC.