# Bootcamp update stopped at version 3.3

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro which I had setup with Bootcamp running Windows 7. I recently upgraded the OS X side to Yosemite as well.

**The exact model is:** Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.2 17" Early 2011

Unfortunately my version of Bootcamp (in Windows) is stuck at 3.3. No updates are coming through for it from within the Apple Software Updater. Why is this? I cannot seem to find any reason why my computer wouldn't have the latest version of bootcamp offered to it.

A very similar question has been asked here: [How do I update my MacBook Pro to the latest version of BootCamp?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200225/how-do-i-update-my-macbook-pro-to-the-latest-version-of-bootcamp) but has no answers.

**Question:** Is Bootcamp v3.3 the maximum version allowed for my software / hardware, or, is there a way other than Apple Software Updater that I should use to update my version of bootcamp? Again, Apple Software Updater is **not** releasing the latest version to me (despite the fact that it did provide me Bootcamp updates in the past up until v3.3)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Let's close this and promote the question that has no answers. Unless your question is materially different, we prefer to keep all the answers, wrong answers, false starts on the main thread. See [help] for guidance on this.

Comment: Could you edit this to list your exact OS X version and your exact BootCamp version. We can release the hold if you have a question that isn't what the linked one is asking. I'm tempted to close that as too broad as well since it seems to be asking for a tutorial as opposed to what we like to have here - a narrow question showing research and asking one thing clearly.

Comment: @bmike, I've taken a stab at rephrasing my question with additional information. Please review when you have a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Windows 7 (32bit/64bit) you may download - booted to Windows 7 - the Bootcamp drivers for Windows 7-32bit [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) or Windows 7-64bit [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) for your MacBook Pro Early 2011 directly.

Overview for all supported Mac models: [System requirements to install Windows on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048)

Unzip the downloaded file and start the setup.exe. Or update single drivers with the usual Windows methods.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you know why Bootcamp is not being automatically updated through the Apple Software Update application despite the fact that it used to update through there?

Comment: I have no clue. Maybe your firewall rules or other Windows 7 security measures prohibit the download.

Comment: I'm torn because this fixes my core issue of having bootcamp updated, but does not address my question of whether or not I should have received the update via the Apple Software Update tool or not. I AM receiving other updates via the tool such as iCloud, QuickTime, iTunes, etc. If no more answers come in, in the next 24 hours, I'll accept this and reward the bounty. Thank you very much for your help.